# Mysql ORDER BY not sorting data properly

Tags: mysql, database

mysql order by query is not working for me properly. anyone please let me know whether there is any problem with query or this is kind of bug.

See attached image for query and result.

[image]

Comment: Can it be that there is a blank in front of "Dr"?

Comment: what happens if you run this query from `mysql` command prompt?

Comment: @Jens is very likely correct. However, depending on what Unicode abilities you have enabled it could also be a Unicode which looks like but is not a D and which is ordered prior to A. I'd go with the space though.

Comment: @Jens Yes, blank space was there.fixed and worked well. thanks.